# Get all pixels of specified color from PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to get all pixels of a specified color (either from ARGB or any from the `Color` class) in C#. My first idea was to draw the picturebox content into a `Bitmap`, then using `for` loop, iterate through the pixels using `b.GetPixel(x, y);`. However, the PictureBox I am using is huge, so it would take few millions/tens of millions iterations to check this, which is way too performance-unfriendly. Does anyone have a better solution than this? Thanks

Comment: You are looking for [Bitmap.Lockbits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I hardly see how you could verify each pixel and pick the ones you want, without checking each pixel. Looks like you're stuck with O(n), unless of course you use an heuristic that would lower the accuracy (like predicting the surrounding pixels). It's like trying to count an array without going through each element, you're bounded to O(n), it's impossible. And the alternatives you may find probably all fall back on looking at each pixels one by one internally anyway.

Comment: How big are the images You want to process? Maybe using `Lockbits()` mentioned in earlier comment and combining it with unsafe image processing code will give You acceptable performance, despite checking each pixel.

Comment: Using LockBits is amazingly fast; I hope you're not doing it in real-time, though..!

Comment: I just wrote a sample code to check color pixel by pixel and just count number of matching pixels using `Lockbits()` and `unsafe` pixel data access and on my machine it took about ***90*** milliseconds to process ***1920x1080*** image (***2073600*** pixels to check). You can find some sample of unsafe pixel data access here: http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/fastest-image-merge-%28alpha-blend%29-in-gdi2b. Please let me know if You want some help during the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote extension methods for System.Drawing.Image that iterate over every pixel in the image and return a List containing every x/y coordinate as System.Drawing.Point.
You can search for rgb values or rgba values.
My methods are using pointers, so you need to enable unsafe code for your project.
Iterating over bitmaps with a pointer is many times faster compared to GetPixel(...).
In this blog entry GetPixel(...) is claimed to be more than 1000 times slower compared to a pointer based solution.
 http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/14/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-ii/
You should test this code properly before using it, but even if something is incorrect the techniques shown should get you started!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static class Pixelcounter
{
    private struct PixeldataARGB
    {
        public byte b;
        public byte g;
        public byte r;
        public byte a;
    }

    private struct PixeldataRGB
    {
        public byte b;
        public byte g;
        public byte r;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Point> CountOccurences(this Image @this, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        if (r < 0 || g < 0 || b < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("color values must not be negative");
        if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
            throw new ArgumentException("color values must be below 256");

        return CountOccurences(@this, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b);
    }

    public static unsafe IEnumerable<Point> CountOccurences(this Image @this, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@this);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        PixeldataRGB* pointer = (PixeldataRGB*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>();

        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
            {
                PixeldataRGB current = *pointer;
                if (current.r == r && current.g == g && current.b == b)
                    pointList.Add(new Point(x, y));
                pointer++;
            }
        }

        bitmap.Dispose();

        return pointList;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Point> CountOccurences(this Image @this, int r, int g, int b, int a)
    {
        if (r < 0 || g < 0 || b < 0 || a < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("color and alpha values must not be negative");
        if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255 || a > 255)
            throw new ArgumentException("color and alpha values must be below 256");

        return CountOccurences(@this, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b, (byte)a);
    }

    public static unsafe IEnumerable<Point> CountOccurences(this Image @this, byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@this);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        PixeldataARGB* pointer = (PixeldataARGB*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>();

        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
            {
                PixeldataARGB current = *pointer;
                if (current.r == r && current.g == g && current.b == b && current.a == a)
                    pointList.Add(new Point(x, y));
                pointer++;
            }
        }

        bitmap.Dispose();

        return pointList;
    }
}
```